# Simply changing dimention of input layer from 2 to 10

Tags: tensorflow

This is my first code which works well.

Inputs are 2 dimensions and outputs are 2 dimensions

First Code:

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2,1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))


x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,2])
t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,1])
y = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x,w) + b)

cross_entropy = - tf.reduce_sum(t * tf.log(y) + (1-t) * 
                                tf.log(1 -y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.to_float(tf.greater(y,0.5)),t)


X = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
Y = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[1]])

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for epoch in range(200):
    sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={
        x:X,
        t:Y
    })
```

Now I want to extend this to 10 dimensions inputs and 2 dimensions outputs.

Then I changed like this below , however it shows error
.
I know this error is related with size of placeholder, however 
Where should I change and why???

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wisdom2.py", line 57, in <module>
    t: Y
  File "/Users/whitebear/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 789, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/whitebear/tensorflow/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 975, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (5, 1) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 10)'
```

Second Code:

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,1])) ## change dimensions to 2 -> 10
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,10]) # change dimensions to 2 -> 10
t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,1])
y = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x,w) + b)

cross_entropy = - tf.reduce_sum(t * tf.log(y) + (1 -t) * tf.log(1 -y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.to_float(tf.greater(y,0.5)),t)

##I changed here....
X = np.array([[0],[1],[0],[1],[1]]) #answer
Y = np.array([
[2,-2,3,-4,2,2,3,5,3,6],  
[1,3,-3,2,2,5,1,3,2,3],   
[-2,3,2,-2,2,-2,1,3,4,5],   
[-2,2,-1,-2,2,-2,7,3,9,2],   
[-2,-3,2,-2,2,-4,1,-4,4,5]   
])


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for epoch in range(200):
    sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={
        x: X,
        t: Y
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are feeding the wrong shapes as inputs to the `placeholders`. You have changed your dimension of `x` in the placeholder but feeding it the wrong input `X` (which you have not changed) but instead of `y` (which you have changed). So either swap X, y or change the appropriate `placeholders`

Comment: I simply mistaken gave XY data reversely. thanks very much